# Android: Run only single functions in a thread and not parallel

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a single Thread, which should execute some functions after one function is completed (Function 1 => Function 2 => Function 3).
My code

```
public class Foo () {
    ....
    /* Some android stuff here */
    myTestThread Foo = new myTestThread();
    Foo.execute();
    ....

    public void function1 () {
        /* Some code stuff */
    }
    public void function2 () {
        /* Some code stuff */
    }

    public class myTestThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {          
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
              function1();
              function2();
        }
    }
}
```

As fair as I know, a single thread runs parallel to an existing programme code, so the myTestThread should run parallel. But I want to call the functions (function1, function2) AFTER the first one is finished. At the moment, both functions are called to the same time.
So what is my mistake?

See my comment: I had called close and disconnect but close is enough. Now, it seems to work. Shame on me :(

Comment: "functions (function1, function2)...both functions are called to the same time" - If your post accurately reflects your actual code, I don't believe they are.

Comment: But they do. Both functions using network access (UDP) and bind to a DatagramSocket using the same ports (why is here unimportant). Before finishing there work, the socket is closed and disconnect. When running just one function is everything okay, but more than one results in a java.bind.exception, so the functions should run at the same time and try to use the same port (but this is illegal).

Comment: No, that is a different issue, and these do not run in parallel.  What you really have is a networking question, not a threading one, so that is the code you need to post, either as a drastic edit to this, or by deleting this question and posting a new one on the subject of why you get that error, **including the code of the networking methods**.